# How do I create horizontal scrollable list of html cards like chrome search results on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am trying to create a horizontal scrollable list of cards just like any Google search results of Chrome on any mobile device.It shouldn't have any scrollbar, must scroll left and right with clicking and dragging simultaneously on the cards.The scrolling on the right is going to infinite.My target device is a desktop.
[I am trying to replicate this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL89C.jpg)

Comment: lots of content scrolling scripts around . If you get stuck can look at source of https://benfrain.com/playground/scroller.html. I used it a few days ago to build a specialized scroller

Comment: Note the scroll bar does dissapear with settings and some css

Comment: This is what I was lookig for perhaps I didn't understood earlier.Thanks