# How to create scroll-able row of cards like the one implemented by DuckDuckGo/Google search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can the following row of cards be implemented?

[image]

referenced the following link but it has no answers
[How do I create horizontal scrollable list of html cards like chrome search results on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139818/how-do-i-create-horizontal-scrollable-list-of-html-cards-like-chrome-search-resu)

https://benfrain.com/playground/scroller.html is too complicated.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cardRow {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: #222;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  width: 200px;
  /*Not working???*/
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #34495e
}
```

```html
<div class="cardRow">
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
  <div class="card">Card Content</div>
</div>
```

The number of cards remaining being displayed when hovered on the arrows isn't necessary. Just the arrows that control scroll is okay.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: you can roughly achieve this by using jQuery sliders like slick